# NServiceBus 5 - Sql Transport not writing audit records

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus5

I am using the sql transport and have the following defined in my config file for the sender and endpoint.

```
<section name="AuditConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.AuditConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />    
<AuditConfig QueueName="audit" />
```

The tables get successfully created, however, when my message handlers complete successfully and i check the tables no records are present. Is there something else I need to do to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: If ServiceControl is running it is probably consuming these messages, could that be the issue?

Comment: hmm i went it and looked at pulse and insight and did not see anything. so you are saying these tools would delete from the audit queue??

Comment: Yes, ServiceControl by default will consume the messages from the Audit and Error queues. It more or less takes their place in the auditing and error debugging side of things. Auditing via Service Insight and Error debugging and manual retries via ServicePulse, both of them get their data from ServiceControl.

Answer (score 0):

Low and behold this was an error within the outbox and a fix has been committed.

https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/2702